# How do I retrieve the data from an iPhone 5 that was backed up on iCloud, if I forgot the passcode to the iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, password, data-recovery

I used to use an iPhone 5. Then I transitioned to an Android and forgot the password on the iPhone. I want to retrieve the data, including photos, recordings (I used the app called "Voice Recorder & Audio Editor"), contacts, and game data. I have not backed up the data on iTunes, but I believe I backed it up on iCloud (I know the Apple ID). I also think I had Find My iPhone on, in case that helps. I do not want to factory reset my iphone because that would delete all the data; the whole point is to retrieve the data.

I would be ok with jailbreaking the phone or bypassing the password in any way, but I need to retrieve the data.

The iphone had the latest version that was made available for iphone 5 (at some point apple stopped letting iphone 5 upgrade further).

I had the "custom passcode" on or whatever it's called (the one where you can use any number of digits).

For reference: I have 2 windows computers available to use: one has windows 7, and one has windows 10.

How can I retrieve the data from my iPhone 5?

Comment: Do you know the password for you AppleID with the iCloud backup of the data?

Comment: Yes I know the AppleID.